# ASP.net Identity in New ERM based Project

Tags: asp.net, webforms, asp.net-identity

I have been ordered to use Identity in a new Web forms based project instead of old Membership. But on the web there are very few resources related to Webforms as compared to MVC. Even on ASP.NET/Identity there are just 2 articles on webforms. What should I do in this regard. What would you do in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a sample application from Visual Studio it sets it all up for you you can then look there to see what it does and how it's setup.